# How to fix : BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit')

Tags: visualstudio, mobile-automation, specflow, .net, azure-devops

I am trying to **build task** in Azure pipeline. Observed error :

> **OneTimeSetUp: BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.IUnitTestRuntimeProvider('nunit')**

Please let me know if anyone face/fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution :

- Add **SpecFlow.NUnit** package to your project [.csproj file]

```
<PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.NUnit">
     <Version>3.1.97</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Note -
You need to add version similar to version of SpecFlow package you are using in your project